# Fetch matching data otherwise standard data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have below 2 tables:

Table_1

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pr1 | C1 | Type A |
| Pr2 | C2 | Type B |
| Pr3 | C3 | Type C |
| Pr4 | C4 | Type A |
| Pr5 | C5 | Type A |

MappingTable

| Col4 | LookupCol2 | LookupCol3 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | C1 | Type A | Yes |
| 1111 |  | Type A | No |
| 1111 |  | Type B | No |
| 1111 |  | Type C | No |
| 2222 | C1 | Type A | Yes |
| 2222 | C2 | Type A | Yes |
| 2222 |  | Type A | No |
| 2222 |  | Type B | No |
| 2222 |  | Type C | No |

```
    CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([Col1] varchar(3), [Col2] varchar(2), [Col3] varchar(5))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    ([Col1], [Col2], [Col3])
VALUES
    ('Pr1', 'C1', 'TypeA'),
    ('Pr2', 'C2', 'TypeB'),
    ('Pr3', 'C3', 'TypeC'),
    ('Pr4', 'C4', 'TypeA')
;


CREATE TABLE MappingTable
    ([Col4] int, [lookupCol2] varchar(4), [lookupCol3] varchar(5), [Col5] varchar(3))
;
    
INSERT INTO MappingTable
    ([Col4], [lookupCol2], [lookupCol3], [Col5])
VALUES
    (1111, 'C1', 'TypeA', 'Yes'),
    (1111, NULL, 'TypeA', 'No'),
    (1111, NULL, 'TypeB', 'No'),
    (1111, NULL, 'TypeC', 'No'),        
    (2222, 'C1', 'TypeA', 'Yes'),
    (2222, 'C2', 'TypeA', 'Yes'),
    (2222, NULL, 'TypeA', 'No'),
    (2222, NULL, 'TypeB', 'No'),
    (2222, NULL, 'TypeC', 'No')
;
```

I have written below Query which is generating incorrect data:

```
select a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4, b.col5 
from Table1 A
inner join
  MappingTable B
   on a.Col3  = b.lookupcol3
   and a.Col2 = case when b.lookupcol2 is null then a.col2 else b.lookupcol2 end
```

Screenshot of incorrect data:
[image]
Desired Result

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pr1 | C1 | Type A | 1111 | Yes |
| Pr1 | C1 | Type A | 2222 | Yes |
| Pr2 | C2 | Type B | 1111 | No |
| Pr2 | C2 | Type B | 2222 | No |
| Pr3 | C3 | Type C | 1111 | No |
| Pr3 | C3 | Type C | 2222 | No |
| Pr4 | C4 | Type A | 1111 | No |
| Pr4 | C4 | Type A | 2222 | No |
| Pr5 | C5 | Type A | 1111 | No |
| Pr5 | C5 | Type A | 2222 | No |

The requirement is to fetch the mapping data for every Col1 record from the mapping table.

Concern:

The Table1 key columns Col2 and Col3 has a mapping record for Pr1 in mapping table, so the matched record can be pulled directly but the key columns for Pr4 and Pr5 are not matching for Col2. In the mapping table, If the lookupcol2 is blank for any  Col4 and lookupCol3 combination then it is a standard record, so in the Pr4 and Pr5 case, the query should fetch the standard record where lookupCol2 is blank.

Am not sure what am I missing here.

Comment: Is the result shown your desired result or your actual result (we need your desired result). Also adding your sample data as DDL+DML makes it much easier for us to answer.

Comment: I have shown the desired result. The sample data (which I cannot share) is almost looks similar to the dummy data.

Comment: Of course you can't share your sample data, but you should be creating a complete [mre] for us with sample data (ideally as DDL+DML), desired results and a query.

Comment: I have to admit it took me quite some time to work out your logic. There must be a better way to explain it.

Comment: Understood your concern. unfortunately i logged into a system where there is no SQL editor. I took some time to find out online editor to create the DDL+DML statements. And by the I was ready I saw your response. apoligies for the delay.

Comment: For future reference https://dbfiddle.uk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `dense_rank` solution to flag up results which have a specific record and a standard record and filter them out.

```
declare @Table_1 table (Col1 varchar(3), Col2 varchar(2), Col3 varchar(6));

insert into @Table_1 (Col1, Col2,   Col3)
values
('Pr1', 'C1', 'Type A'),
('Pr2', 'C2', 'Type B'),
('Pr3', 'C3', 'Type C'),
('Pr4', 'C4', 'Type A'),
('Pr5', 'C5', 'Type A');

declare @MappingTable table (Col4 varchar(4), LookupCol2 varchar(6), LookupCol3 varchar(6), Col5 bit);

insert into @MappingTable (Col4, LookupCol2, LookupCol3, Col5)
values
('1111', 'C1', 'Type A', 1),
('1111', '', 'Type A', 0),
('1111', '', 'Type B', 0),
('1111', '', 'Type C', 0),
('2222', 'C1', 'Type A', 1),
('2222', 'C2', 'Type A', 1),
('2222', '', 'Type A', 0),
('2222', '', 'Type B', 0),
('2222', '', 'Type C', 0);

with cte as (
    select A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3, B.Col4, B.Col5
        -- If a specific and standard record exists this will be 2 for the standard record
        , dense_rank() over (partition by A.Col1, A.Col2, A.Col3 order by B.LookupCol2 desc) rn
    from @Table_1 A
    inner join @MappingTable B on A.Col3  = B.LookupCol3
        and A.Col2 = case when B.LookupCol2 = '' then A.Col2 else B.LookupCol2 end
)
select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5
from cte
-- Filter out the standard records when a specific record exists
-- Comment out the following line and add rn to the output to understand how it works
where rn = 1
order by Col1, Col2;
```

Returns:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pr1 | C1 | Type A | 1111 | 1 |
| Pr1 | C1 | Type A | 2222 | 1 |
| Pr2 | C2 | Type B | 1111 | 0 |
| Pr2 | C2 | Type B | 2222 | 0 |
| Pr3 | C3 | Type C | 1111 | 0 |
| Pr3 | C3 | Type C | 2222 | 0 |
| Pr4 | C4 | Type A | 1111 | 0 |
| Pr4 | C4 | Type A | 2222 | 0 |
| Pr5 | C5 | Type A | 1111 | 0 |
| Pr5 | C5 | Type A | 2222 | 0 |

Note the DDL+DML which if you add to your questions makes them much easier to answer (because we don't have to type it all in).

Comment: Thank you Dale for the quick response but the result is not matching with your query output. I see value '0' for Pr1 under Col5. I sorted the lookcol2 column in descending order and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @user994860 I made a very small mistake... can you work out where? Try uncommenting the bits I suggested for debugging.